# cannot access object from react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux, undefined

I have got the data from reducer and display it in console [image: console display]

but when i want to access specific object for example (table.nomor) and it become error
[image]

this is for my reducer:

```
export const orderListDetailReducer = (state = { orders: {} }, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case ORDER_TABLE:
        return {
            orders: action.payload
        }
    default:
        return state;
}
}
```

this is for my screen:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { listOrderDetail } from '../actions/orderAction'


const PlaceOrderScreen = (props) => {
const orderId = props.match.params.id
const orderListDetail = useSelector(state => state.orderListDetail)
const { orders } = orderListDetail

const dispatch = useDispatch()

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listOrderDetail(orderId))
}, [dispatch, orderId])

console.log(orders.table.nomor);
```

Comment: Try to log orders object in your component. It should contain just the initial state, since useEffect() doesn't change the state in the current render

Comment: it same, i only can access the object (orders.table), but cannot access the subobject (orders.table.nomor)

Comment: It's supposed to be the same. I'm trying to say that you don't have problem with access but rather with initialization, since orders is in it's initial state when you try to access its properties. Does it contain orders.table field in initial state?

Comment: ya it containts orders.table

Comment: `useEffect` is executed _after_ the initial render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem: undefined in initial state

The first render of your component happens before the dispatched action has completed its update of the store.  That means that the value of `state` on your first render is the initial value (unless you have already updated the state from some other component).

Your initial state is `state = { orders: {} }` so the initial value of `orders` is an empty object `{}`.  You can access `orders.table` on the empty object, but the value of `orders.table` is `undefined`.  You **cannot** access `orders.table.nomor` because that would be trying to get the property `nomor` from `orders.table` which is `undefined` -- so you get the error *"Cannot read property 'nomor' of undefined".*

You need to make sure that your component can render properly at any point in the lifecycle, whether or not the `ORDER_TABLE` action has been completed.

#### Solution 1: guarded access

You can make sure that `orders.table` is not `undefined` before accessing the `.nomor` property.

```
const nomor = orders.table ? orders.table.nomor : someDefaultValue;
```

Or more concisely with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```
const nomor = orders.table?.nomor; // will be undefined if not able to access
```

#### Solution 2: initial value

You can set a deeper initial value object for your reducer which allows you to access `orders.table.nomor`.  This may or may not make sense depending on your app's data structures.

If `orders.table` is an empty object `{}` instead of `undefined`, then it will be ok to access `orders.table.nomor`.  The value of  `orders.table.nomor` in this case is `undefined`.

```
const initialState = {
  orders: {
     table: {}
  }
}
```

You can also go one level deeper and set an initial value for `nomor`.

```
const initialState = {
  orders: {
     table: {
       nomor: someInitialValue
     }
  }
}
```

Either way, you would use this as the initial value for your reducer.

```
export const orderListDetailReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

this is common issue with async behavior on react-redux store, you need to understand useSelector works async and to check the variable with full values you need to use a useEffec, check the following example:

***try the code and tell me how goes :)

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { listOrderDetail } from '../actions/orderAction'


const PlaceOrderScreen = (props) => {
const orderId = props.match.params.id
const orders = useSelector(state => state.orderListDetail.orders)//-->changed this line -->added one level
//const { orders } = orderListDetail //-->commented this line

const dispatch = useDispatch()

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listOrderDetail(orderId))
}, [dispatch, orderId])


//-->create new useEffect and add the dependency from useSelector constant
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('orders',orders);
    console.log('nomor',orders.table.nomor);
}, [orders]);
```

Comment: that can be because of the level on the object try doing a desctructuring like :            
   const { table } =  orders ; then console log --> console.log(table.nomor)